# How to generate java/android signature block file (.RSA) with php (phpseclib)

Tags: android, apk, digital-signature, phpseclib, php-openssl

I’m trying to sign an android .apk file on the server completely with php.

For this I need to generate the files contained in META-INF directory inside the .apk file(which is essentially a ZIP file). Creating the .MF and .SF files in php is fairly simple. However, I'm struggling with the .RSA file.

Unfortunately, I don’t know anything about cryptography and don’t even understand the basic terms. I only know some PHP basics, but I’m far from experienced and have no overview of the necessary libraries/functions. Therefore even after many hours of research, I still wasn’t able to create anything useful.

From what I understand, the .RSA file should contain:

- digital signature of the .SF file
- certificate with signers public key

This file should be PKCS7 formatted.

I was trying to use the phpseclib for this. I was able to create a private/public key/certificate from the examples on the internet, but I’m absolutely not able to put it all together to form the .RSA file.

Stackoverflow has been a great source of information and I probably found most of the answers to my questions here. However, now I’m stuck.

Could you guys please give me some php example code(ideally)? Or even some pseudocode/algorithm…
Is this even possible to accomplish with phpseclib/php? Will there be some “bit shifting” necessary? 
If possible, please don’t point me to the source code of jarsigner…I looked at it, but don’t know much about java and it only brought more questions.

## Update:

It’s hard to move in the right direction when you have no idea what you are actually doing :D…

This is what I tried so far, but without any success:

1. I generated public/private key pair with ssh

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa1`
2. I used the previously generated keypair to create a self-signed certificate with phpsceclib as described here:
   http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/new/x509/tutorial.html#selfsigning
3. I passed the certificate ($signcert), private key ($privkey - from ssh generated file) and data for signing ($infilename –> the .SF file) to the openssl function openssl_pkcs7_sign():

   `openssl_pkcs7_sign ($infilename , $outfilename , $signcert , $privkey , array(), PKCS7_DETACHED|PKCS7_BINARY);`

However, the generated result seems to be in something called PEM format (human readable). Besides the fact that it’s not in binary DER (don’t even know what that is…just guessing that it should be DER) which the final .RSA file should be, there are also some other issues with it:

- the result also contains the content of the .SF file (the original data to be signed itself)
- it contains some unnecessary header information as regular text string
- lines end with “\n” and not with “\r\n”
- the signature (not really sure what the other data in the result is, but probably the signature) is base64 encoded

Am I doing at least something right here? What other steps have to be taken to make it work? What properties should I set when creating the certificate according to the mentioned link? How could I transfer the result to binary DER-formatted .RSA file containing the .SF signature and certificate with signers public key?

## Update 2:

I finally had some time to continue with my little experiment. I went through my code and tried to change different parameters. Finally I found the issue. It seems that I only needed to turn on the PKCS7_NOATTR flag in the openssl_pkc7_sign().

Here is the code

```
$configs = array('digest_alg' => 'sha1', 
                 'x509_extensions' => 'v3_ca',
                 'req_extensions' => 'v3_req',
                 'private_key_bits' => 1024,
                 'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
                 'encrypt_key' => true,
                 'encrypt_key_cipher' => OPENSSL_CIPHER_3DES);

// Generate private/public key pair and certificate
$privkey = openssl_pkey_new($configs);
$dn = array("commonName" => "name",
            "emailAddress" => "me@example.com");

$csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $privkey, $configs);
$sscert = openssl_csr_sign($csr, NULL, $privkey, 999, $configs);

// Sign the .SF file 
openssl_pkcs7_sign ( $sfFile , $rsaFile , $sscert , $privkey, array(), 
                     PKCS7_DETACHED|PKCS7_BINARY|PKCS7_NOATTR);
```

I only had time to check it on a couple of samples, but it seems to be working now. Here is a very simple demonstration [www.balabeng.com/?q=appsigner](http://www.balabeng.com/?q=appsigner)

Comment: Can you post a sample of the output? It should be possible to write a PHP function to isolate the base64-encoded signature and base64-decode that. That said, I'm wondering...  is there a reason you're using `openssl_pkcs7_sign` instead of `$rsa->sign()` from phpseclib (presumably with pkcs1 padding)?

Comment: openssl_pkcs7_sign produces the required content of the .RSA file. I only need to extract the base64 encoded DER data.
I couldn't find a way to produce the same result with $rsa->sign(). It would be great if you could show me. This way I wouldn't have to rely only on openssl extension.
The .RSA file has to contain a PKCS7 signature (SHA-256 + RSA).